# How does Outlook 2007 decide if it should redirect an e-mail to the Junk E-mail folder?

Tags: outlook, spam, outlook-2007, spam-filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to see why Outlook's client junk mail filter is marking a message as spam?](https://serverfault.com/questions/84469/is-there-any-way-to-see-why-outlooks-client-junk-mail-filter-is-marking-a-messa)

My Question:

> How does Outlook 2007 decide if it
>   should redirect an e-mail to the Junk
>   E-mail folder?

Background Story:
When I send a simple HTML e-mail from my domain mailbox, it's being redirected to the Junk E-mail folder.

Here are two sub questions:

1. Does Outlook 2007 care if the sender's outbound mailbox's reverse PTR is incorrectly configured? [If so, how can it check?]
2. Does Outlook 2007 care if the sender doesn't provide a plain text version of the HTML content?

It turns out, I'm not the only one wondering about Outlook's junk algorithm. See the comments attached to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642211/outlook-marking-email-as-junk-email/2642251#2642251).

Answer (score 1):

There are long lists of weights & scores & reasons emails are dumped into the junk box.  Unfortunately, that information isn't published.  If it was, any spammer could go through the rules & craft emails that would slip through the cracks fairly easily.

If you're trying to keep emails in your network from entering users' junk boxes, you can setup "safe-sender" lists & deploy them via GPO...

If you are sending emails to another office & they're incorrectly being marked as junk... you're going to have a hard time overcoming this.  Generally, you need to look at your email, and verify all the details appear accurate (doubly-so in the message headers)  Look for things like the sent date & time are not unrealistic... check on common spam sender lists to see if your domain/ip is not blacklisted... http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx is a good tool for that.

Also avoid common spam phrases like "advertisement" and "viagra" in the subject lines.  Email addresses with numbers in the first 8 characters are also a common red-flag.  There's a few lists out there with more info, but here's a pretty short one: http://www.streamsend.com/kb2/idx.php/13/106/05-Delivery/article/Tips-to-Avoid-the-Outlook-Junk-Folder.html